# What is the surface area of the surface defined by $z = \frac{k_1}2 x^2 + \frac{k_2}2 y^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, area, surfaces, quadratic-forms

What is the surface area of the 3D saddle surface $f$ defined by
$$
f = [x, y, z(x,y)]
$$
and with
$$
z(x,y) = \frac{k_1}{2} x^2 + \frac{k_2}{2} y^2
$$
for $(x,y)\in(-1,1)\times(-1,1)$ and for any $k_1,k_2\in R$?

---

I am trying to compute it analytically using
$$
A = \iint_{x,y\in(-1,1)^2} \sqrt{\det(I(x,y))} dx dy = \iint_{x,y\in(-1,1)^2} \sqrt{1 + k_1^2 x^2 + k_2^2 y^2} dx dy
$$
where $I$ is the first fundamental form of $f$.

Does any analytical solution exist for this integral?

---

Additional questions: What is the surface area of $f$ for

- $(x,y)$ such that $x^2 + y^2 < 1$ (integral over the unit disk)
- $(x,y)$ such that $x^2 + y^2 + z(x,y)^2 < 1$ (integral over the intersection of the surface with the unit ball)